# Continuity of derivative of a continuous monotone function

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, continuity

We know that every continuous monotone function defined on [a, b] possesses a finite derivative almost everywhere.

What about the continuity of the derivative? Can I say that the derivative of this function is continuous almost everywhere?

Or if we define $\tilde f(x) = \liminf_{y \to x-} \frac{f(y)-f(x)}{y-x}$, what is the continuity of $\tilde f(x)$? Is that continuous almost everywhere?

Comment: Let $g$ be a positive integrable function on $[a,b]$. What is $$x \mapsto \int_a^x g(t)\,dt\,?$$

Comment: Hi Daniel, how does this relate to the question?

Comment: If you look hard, you'll see a continuous monotonic function and its derivative. You can assume that $g$ is the most regular representative of its equivalence class in $L^1$. So the derivatives of continuous monotonic functions can be quite bad.